# Why does the Android emulator miss-size the screen sometimes?

Tags: android, android-emulator

On occasion, my Android Emulator makes the size of the screen smaller than the emulator and fills in the empty space with the color red.

[image]

This is solved by resizing the emulator.  But I want to know **why does this happen in the first place?**

Comment: Are you using react native?  That looks more like a react native thing than an emulator thing.

Comment: @GabeSechan does React Native affect the status bar and navigation bar?

Comment: @GabeSechan I am not using react native.